# How to make my WordPress installation on Google Cloud use my Google domain name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress

I am running a WordPress installation on Google Cloud, and I have a domain hosted with Google. I have successfully mapped Cloud DNS to my Google domain. When I try to browse to my site http://example.com/ it redirects me to http://192.0.2.88/.

How can I change it, so it does not redirect me to the IP address?

Comment: Open it in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you shared, the issue might point to a misconfiguration inside wordpress since you have successfully mapped Cloud DNS to your google domain.

I understand that you are tying to display your domain in the search bar instead of your IP.
Here's [a link](https://serverpilot.io/docs/solution-to-wordpress-showing-ip-address-instead-of-domain/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20installed%20WordPress%20using,General%20Settings%2C%20as%20shown%20below) which guide you how to fix this issue.